# Propel match email validator is wrong?

Tags: email, match, propel

Im try use a Propel match validators. In this case a email string.
I use the example from Propel Docs:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([\.a-zA-Z0-9_-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9])+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+$/
```

But, this regex fails always.
Ex: pepe@mail.com, ramiro@gmail.com, messi.10@barsa.ca, js_veron@hotmail.com.ar

Any idea ?

Comment: The regex looks ok and validate these emails

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that never assign a email value u.u
Thanks !